# Wordpress adding -1 to url even when page is a child page

Tags: wordpress

My title may be confusing, but hopefully a simple problem.  I have a page "Classes", and another page "Account / Classes".  I'd like both pages to have slug "classes".

1. site.com/classes
2. site.com/account/classes

For some reason it's detecting a conflict and renaming it to /account/classes-1.  There are no other "classes" pages.  I know it will do this if 2 pages are on the same hierarchy, but shouldn't with subpages, I would think.

Any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: Update - trash is empty, no draft posts.

Answer (score 0):

It was a slug modifier plugin causing the issue.  Marking this solved.  Thanks for looking!